# Task Module returns blank screen Microsoft Teams

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

I used sample provided by microsoft at [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp) and pushed this code to my already created bot in MS Teams to test. Whenever, I try to click on any card button, I get a blank screen and only the button "Adaptive Card" seems to work, where as the ZIP provided in the github link works fine when published on teams.

[[image]]

I have tried changing manifest settings but nothing helps.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added the domain of the URL you are trying to open, in valid domains? Also Could you please share your app manifest?

Comment: As @Nikitha-MSFT says, this is almost always related to the domain not being in the "Valid domains" list.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it using "valid domains" but still when i fill custom form and submit I don't get Task/Submit event at the bot end. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT,  when i fill custom form and submit I don't get Task/Submit event at the bot end.. is there anything I am missing at my end? I tried publishing the same github code to my bot and it isn't working.

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT, could you answer the question, and also give an example, when we load page www.abc.com, and inside it we load from api and oauth from say www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com. should all of them added into the valid domains? it would be helpful for other that came accross this issue like me